# Call method on included class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How do you call the method of an included class in Ruby? See the example below. This works, but it is not what I want:

```
require 'httparty'

module MyModule
  class MyClass
    include HTTParty
    base_uri 'http://localhost'        

    def initialize(path)
      # other code
    end

  end
end
```

This is what I want, but doesn't work, saying `undefined method 'base_uri' [...]`. What I'm trying to do is to set the base_uri of httparty dynamically from the initialize parameter.

```
require 'httparty'

module MyModule
  class MyClass
    include HTTParty

    def initialize(path)
      base_uri 'http://localhost'
      # other code
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [HTTParty source code](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb), `base_uri` is a class method.
So you would need to call the method on the class context

```
module MyModule
  class MyClass
    include HTTParty

    def initialize(path)
      self.class.base_uri 'http://localhost'
      # other code
    end

  end
end
```

Beware that this solution might not be thread safe, depending on how you use your library.

Comment: Can you throw more light on the thread safe issue? In ruby on rails we have multiple processes. is it safe in that case? Two processes could change the classes base_uri simultaneously. How does that work?